# How to create a blog with only index.html, style.css and script.js files?

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogs

Inspiration for blog listing pages:
https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing

https://www.igomoon.com/blog

I only want to know from where should I start? from the beginning of the first line code? or Can import sample codes and edit them?

Should I develop index.html and style.css first? and after that script.js?

Comment: Without a proper backend (like PHP & mysql) you need to simulate a database. You could use JSON for that and build HTML from the data using JavaScript. I don't think this is a sensible route to go though; you should acquire the required backend skills first (basic PHP and DB queries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different approaches on how to realize such a project in general, strongly depending on what your skills are and how do you want to achieve your goals.

For example: If you already know how to write a page in simple HTML, do that first and build your skeleton in HTML. If you have placed all the things where you want to have them, you will find out that they are not looking very nice. If you know how to work with CSS you will add then your CSS. If you don't know how to work with CSS you need to learn that.

Once you have styled it with CSS you will figure out, that you page need to be filled with content and you will ask yourself how to do that. Then there are again several ways on how to do that. For example you maybe want to catch some data from Server X but don't know how to do that. You'll figure out, that you can fetch some data with node.js and then you need to learn node.js.

It's a ongoing process of figuring out:
1.) What you want to do
2.) Check out how to do that
3.) Learn the necessary skills
4.) Repeat points 1 to 3